# Verb agreement: The behavior of X and Y "was" or "were" considered?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number, compound-subjects

Which is correct of the following (or better to use):

> The behavior of X and Y **was** considered.

or

> The behavior of X and Y **were** considered.

Comment: The behaviour .....was considered!

Comment: To expand on Absolute Beginner's comment a little, the subject of the sentence is "The behavior".  That's singular, so it has to be *was considered*.  Whether the behavior is *of X and Y*, or *of an angry invisible elephant*, or whatever, makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Subject-verb agreement is a pain even for native speakers.  The trick is to find the actual subject of the sentence and ignore the rest.  For example:

> The **boat** that belongs to Steve, Jim, Jeff, Harry, Rick, Marty, Wally, and George **is** red.
>
> All of the **books** owned by Steve **are** in that box.

This gets interesting with pronouns like everyone, anyone, each of them, no one, and so on.  [More information](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm)

Lastly you should be aware that British English treats some collective nouns as singular, where American English treats them as plural.  For example,

> The other team *are* sitting down / The other team *is* sitting down.
>
> The crowd *are* really enjoying the match / The crowd *is* enjoying the match.

[More information on the differences between BrE and AmE](http://www.onestopenglish.com/grammar/grammar-reference/american-english-vs-british-english/differences-in-american-and-british-english-grammar-article/152820.article#agreement)